# appending row number in sql select statement with row value

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to concatenate the select statment results in one row.
For eg :
For this select statement output :

```
Name  
ABC  
DEF  
GHI
```

I needed following Output :
Name

```
1 ABC, 2 DEF, 3 GHI
```

(Means row number should be appended in front for each row)
I am using wm_concat() function but it is giving me the following o/p : `ABC,DEF,GHI`
Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want something similar to this. The `listagg()` function is available in Oracle 11g+:

```
select listagg(cast(rownum as varchar2(20))||' '|| name, ', ') 
        within group (order by name) name
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c93ef/1)

Results:

```
|                NAME |
-----------------------
| 1 ABC, 2 DEF, 3 GHI |
```

If you do not have Oracle 11g, then you can use `wm_concat()`:

```
select wm_concat(cast(rownum as varchar2(20))||' '|| name) name
from yourtable
```

Comment: LISTAGG() is only available since Oracle 11r2.

Comment: @apc correct they did not specify version. If not oracle 11g then use of wm_concat() can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Additionaly you could use WITH clause:

```
WITH tmp AS 
(
   :your_select_statement 
)
SELECT 
  LISTAGG(rownum || ' ' || :your_column, ', ') 
  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY :your_column) tmp
FROM tmp;
```

Then rownum is from tmp temporary table which have results of :your_select_statement not from primary table.